# How does this interpretation of Chebyshev's theorem fail for the sample mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Being the Chebyshev inequality for the sample mean as:

$$P(|x̄−u|\ge kσ) \le\frac{σ^2}{e^2}$$

Where  $$e=kσ$$ $$E(x̄)=u$$  $$Var(x̄)=σ^2/n $$

replacing the values:

$$P[|x̄−u|\ge k\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}}]\le\frac{\frac{σ^2}{n}}{k^2\frac{σ^2}{n}}$$

Then,
$$P[|x̄−u|\ge k\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}}]\le\frac{1}{k^2}$$

When n tends to infinity, then the expression:

$$k\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}}$$ tends to zero

However, the expression:
$$\frac{1}{k^2}$$
does not tend to any value, since it should tend to zero

Am I interpreting misinterpreting? Where would the error be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think $P[|\bar{x}-\mu|>k\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}]$ should tend to zero? From Central Limit Theorem we know $\sqrt{n}(\bar{x}-\mu)$ will converge to Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$, which means $P[|\bar{x}-\mu|>k\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}]=P[\sqrt{n}|\bar{x}-\mu|>k\sigma]$ should be of constant scale(actually tend to $P[|Z|>k]$ for $Z\sim N(0,1)$). So your work with Chebyshev gives you a bound on this non-zero quantity--and actually, it is the Chebyshev-type bound for $Z$.

For the law of large numbers, note that here $\bar{x}=\frac{S_n}{n}$ where the latter is what is shown in the note you provide.

$$P[|\bar{x}-\mu|>k\sigma]\leq\frac{Var(\bar{x})}{k^2\sigma^2}=\frac{\sigma^2/n}{k^2\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{kn},$$

which goes to zero. This proves that $\bar{x}$ converges to $\mu$ in probability, which is the (weak)law of large numbers.

Comment: My interpretation is that this expression:
$$k\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}}$$
tends to zero when "n" tends to infinity, noting that the larger "n" is, the difference between (x̄ − μ) becomes smaller, however there is still a difference.
So the expression
$$\frac{1}{k^2}$$
in theory it should have zero so that the interpretation of Chebysheve's theorem is:
"The Probability that (| x-u |> 0.001) is zero, indicating that (x-u) do not differ, and therefore are equal.

Comment: @Christian: The fact is that $(\bar{x}-\mu)$ also depends on $n$, and actually by CLT it is of the same order--which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$--as that of $k\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. So when $n\rightarrow\infty$, $|\bar{x}-\mu|>k\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ is nothing but $\sqrt{n}|\bar{x}-\mu|>k\sigma$, where $\sqrt{n}|\bar{x}-\mu|$ is of order $1$. Therefore the probability should not go to zero.

Comment: Or in other words "the difference between $(\bar{x}-\mu)$ becomes small, however there is still a difference" is incorrect, because you are sending $n$ to infinity while $\bar{x}$ also depends on $n$, thus the difference $(\bar{x}-\mu)$ also goes to zero. It's hard to compare the scale of two quantities both going to zero, that's why we need CLT to quantitatively tell us how fast $(\bar{x}-\mu)$ goes to zero.

Comment: 1) Will you have a PDF to delve into this topic?
////////
2) Under the stage that you show me. How would the "law of large numbers" be proved by Chebyshev's theorem? In this PDF (page 3) the probability tends to zero [PDF (https://www.lkouniv.ac.in/site/writereaddata/siteContent/202004021930364223rajeev_pandey_Law_of_Large_Numbers.pdf)

Comment: @Christian: For your second question, I've added it to the original answer. For your first question, I am not very sure what you mean by "have a PDF to delve into it". If you are asking that whether we need PDF of $\bar{x}$ to apply CLT, the answer is \textbf{NO}, as long as you have finite variance. If you mean what can we say about the asymptotic value of $P[|\bar{x}-\mu|>k\sigma/\sqrt{n}]$, then you need the PDF of standard Gaussian to write out $P[|Z|>k]$. Hope this helps.